# how to save text values in wp_option of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build a function for woocommerce and want to save these data to my wp_option.

```
function custom_before_price() {
                $args = array(
                'id' => 'custom_before_price_table1',
                'label' => __( 'Before Price', 'cbp1' ),
                'class' => 'cbp-custom-field',
                'desc_tip' => true,
                'description' => __( 'Enter the text before price.', 'cbpdes' ),
                );
                   woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
               }

               add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_before_price' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use add_option().something like this

```
add_option( string $option, mixed $value = '', string $deprecated = '', string|bool $autoload = 'yes' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the values to the wp_options table is not a normal WooCommerce behavior. WooCommerce saves product meta in wp_postmeta. There are a lot of possible downsides to storing data about specific products in wp_options. In particular, if you need to return data to the product admin editor from wp_options, you will need to labor on a method for that, as WooCommerce looks to wp_postmeta for custom meta.

The following set of functions will create your custom input and save the value when the product is updated via WP Admin.

```
    /**
    * Create custom meta
    **/
    function custom_before_price() {

        $args = array(
            'id' => 'custom_price',
            'label' => __( 'Custom Price', 'cprice' ),
            'data_type' => 'text', // Let WooCommerce formats our field as price field
            'description' => __( 'Enter the text before price.', 'cprice' ),    
        );

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_before_price' );


    /**
    * Save custom meta
    **/
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_field' );
    function save_custom_field( $post_id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        /*  Get Value */
        $custom_field_value = isset( $_POST['custom_price'] ) ? $_POST['custom_price'] : '';

        /*  Save to _options table (requested answer) */
        $option_name = $post_id.'-custom-price';
        $wpdb->replace(
            'wp_options',
            array(
                'option_name' => $option_name,
                'option_value' => $custom_field_value,
            ),
            array(
                '%s',
                '%s',
            )
        );
    

        /*  Save to postmeta table (normal for woocommerce) */
        $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
        $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_price', $custom_field_value );
        $product->save();

    }
```

Comment: you are right james its working fine,but only one time wp_option is not getting updated
its just storing the first value only and after that its never update but when i saw wp_postmeta 
Its storing and updating there.

Comment: The add_option() function does not update existing rows. I have edited the above to use $wpdb->replace(), which will replace a value or insert a value. I didn't test the edit, let me know if you have issues!

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_before_price() {

    $args = array(
        'id' => 'custom_price',
        'label' => __( 'Custom Price', 'cprice' ),
        'data_type' => 'text', // Let WooCommerce formats our field as price field
        'description' => __( 'Enter the text before price.', 'cprice' ),    
    );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_before_price' );


/**
* Save custom meta
**/
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_field' );
function save_custom_field( $post_id ) {

    /*  Get Value */
    $custom_field_value = isset( $_POST['custom_price'] ) ? $_POST['custom_price'] : '';

    /*  Save to _options table (requested answer) */
    $option_name = $post_id.'-custom-price';
    add_option( $option_name, $custom_field_value );  
/*  its updates in wp_option also*/
    update_option( $option_name ,$custom_field_value );            

    /*  Save to postmeta table (normal for woocommerce) */
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_price', $custom_field_value );
    $product->save();

}
```

Comment: The stackoverflow convention is to refine the answer that was suggested by suggesting an edit, or offering feedback in the comments, and then to accept the answer and not to create multiple nearly identical answers.